# Link of more than just text, useful for SEO?

Tags: css, hyperlink, seo, background-image, image

I have 4 links on a website. Each link goes to a different page (windows, siding, roofing, sunrooms). However, I have set the links up in a different way than normal links. Heres a snippet:

```
<a href="windows.html">
   <div id="img-block">
       <div id="img-link">
           <h1>Windows</h1>
       </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#img-block {
    width:275px;
    height:175px;
    margin:25px 0;
    background-image:url(images/windows.jpg);
    }

#img-link {
    height:40px;
    width:275px;
    margin:135px 0 0 0;
    background-image:url(images/img-link-bg.png);
    }
```

A few reasons for why I did this.  
A) I wanted the image and the text to be click-able 
B) H1 because I've read that google gives Headings a higher rank 
C) Also read that when someone clicks a link, the wording lets google know it was relevant (Clicking "Windows" takes you to a page about windows, increasing the pages rank for "Windows")

Now the question I have is, am I accomplishing all these things? Obviously I've accomplished goal A. but now I can no longer select the text ("windows") on top of the image (because my cursor changes to the hand icon, notifying me of a link)... Also, when I drag the image, it shows that I'm dragging the image, the img-link image, and the text all as one, as if it were one image.

Hope this was clear enough, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going about it all wrong.

You don't need the extra div.

Simply put the background-imgae on the H1 tag itself (and set the height/width of course)
SEO wise, this is an acceptable way of doing things.

You'll be just fine :)

Comment: Thanks! Never thought to set the H1 specifically.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to get your SEO optimized is to include important localized information on the web site, if your site is for a local business its best to include the business address and phone number on every page because google personalizes its search results for most users based on their location and search term context. If I'm in Philadelphia and I type in Vinyl Siding the results I see will be different than the person who types in the same thing in California.  You can't just type in specific headings and magically you'll show up in the first page of the site unless your site contains other relevant information and advertisers always get preferred treatment on google. Index your site using the tools google provides you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I understand the location services used by google. I'm asking a specific question about one part of my optimizing, I'm not expecting my one link in this question to "magically" show me on the first page.

Comment: This does not answer OP question at all.